# .NET Managed Memory Corruption Scenario w/ InProc Session State

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, clr, managed

Had a strange issue that I've never seen in the 12 years I've had with .NET.

After various join.me sessions with a colleague to verify the details, we were able to reproduce it consistently, even as we renamed the session keys involved.

The issue is basically with a **WebForms** app that uses the default **InProc** session provider: **the assignment of one key/value pair impacts a different (unrelated) key repeatably**.

Here's the line of code that was consistently reproducing the issue:

```
Session[UIGlobals.SessionVariable.AgentName.ToString()] = _contact.FullName;
```

It was actually assigning `_contact.FullName` to an **entirely different** session key:

```
Session[UIGlobals.SessionVariable.IsDonorSelectionSubflow.ToString()]
```

Clearly the two enum values produce different string keys but this was a reproducible result. You could reset the execution step to a few lines above the session assignment and note that it changed a different session value (`Session[UIGlobals.SessionVariable.AgentName.ToString()]` remains `null`).

NOTE: assignments done through the immediate window worked as expected.

What finally fixed the issue was deleting the contents of the temp folder all together:

```
<compilation batch="false" defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.0" optimizeCompilations="true" debug="true" tempDirectory="C:\NET_temp">
```

What are some possible explanations that can account for this? Would love to hear some theories as to what class of managed memory corruption this falls under so I can do more reading on it.

Comment: Try that with string constants and see if you can reproduce it. I am very reluctant to believe in managed memory corruption.

Comment: Also, exactly how did you reproduce it? In particular, did you reproduce it in two separate pages? Like you set it in one page, and checked it in another? That's what deleting the temp directory makes me think of.

Comment: I assume that you *were* able to reproduce the issue but now it's resolved and you can no longer reproduce the issue. Your description reminds me of the scenario where the source code didn't match the exe and while debugging it presented as mystifying behavior that didn't make any sense. Not saying it has to be that but it seems to fit all the symptoms you've described. e.g. immediate window works but not the code, clear of the temp folder fixed the issue.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ran through some 25-35 different iterations with this before posting, not able to recreate it after the delete. Was originally reproducible on the same page (setting IsDonorSelectionSubflow to true in immediate window, re-executing the AgentName assignment above, observing that IsDonorSelectionSubflow changed).

Comment: @Tuzo Definitely experienced the scenario you describe, but not the case here... the single line in the app that sets IsDonorSelectionSubflow is nowhere near the AgentName assignment that ultimately determines its value. (Also in TO: look me up on LinkedIn)

Comment: @Nariman: using the immediate window doesn't really constitute "reproducing" the problem. I'm interested in interactions having to do with the ASP.NET page lifecycle, page compilation, appdomain recycles, and interactions with session state. Running in the debugger is not a normal environment for ASP.NET. The fact that the delete "solved" the problem suggests to me a "source code and binaries don't match" issue. In particular, were there _any_ changes at all in the `UIGlobals.SessionVariable` type. In fact, can you show us an example of what that type looks like?